# Increase number of concurrent connections in tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat7

Wondering how to increase the number of concurrent connections in tomcat 7. I did some research and found from apache documentation that setting values to acceptCount, maxConnections and increaseing the maxThreads would do it, but when tried, I was only able to submit 500 requests out of 1000. Below is my snippet from server.xml file -

```
      <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
       maxThreads="2000" acceptCount="1000" maxConnections="1000"
       scheme="https" secure="true"
       keystoreFile="certs/tomcat.keystore" keystorePass="xxxxxxxx"
       clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" server="Apache" />
```

Can you please help me finding out the best and easy way to get rid of this one.?

Thanks,
Sirish.

Comment: You should do a thread dump to find out what's blocking the requests, because you _have_ configured 2000 threads (max but not min, so Tomcat will need to create more threads on the fly). However, 2000 threads is huge, are you sure you need so many?

Comment: Hi Frank, I'm just playing around to find if increasing threads makes any difference and also aware it would lead to memory issues. At this point I would like to configure the server to accept as many connections as possible without defaulting to 200 threads (as set by tomcat by default). am curious to know how to do a thread dump by the way.? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank.!!

Comment: To get a thread dump, you can `kill -3 PID` (if you're on some Unix; there's a Ctrl-something combination on Windows to achieve the same result) which will print the thread dump on the standard output, or use `jstack PID > threads.txt`, jstack being part of the JDK. Even if you only have 200 threads, if they're all used by concurrent requests it's going to be a _long_ read to analyze.

Answer (score 14):

Creating a large number of threads<sup>1</sup> and accepting a large number of requests doesn't mean that your server will be able to process the requests

If you have N threads and only M physical processors / cores, then each thread will get 1 processor if `M >= N` and an average `M / N` processors if `M < N`.  Assume you have N requests each running on a 1 thread, and each request takes `R` seconds of CPU time.  The average elapsed time `T` taken to run one request is `T = Min(R, R * N / M) seconds`.  It is fairly clear that as you increase `N` (the number of active threads and active requests) the average elapsed time `T` for each individual request increases proportionally.

In addition to that, if you have lots of threads, they will all be using memory, and all will be competing for access to shared data structures ... or the database.  An all of this extra resource usage and contention is increasing the overheads of the system as a whole in various ways.

So, what I suspect is happening is that with that number of threads each trying to process requests simultaneously, the time `T` is starting to approach the client or server side request timeout.  (And note that the vagaries of the scheduler, etc mean that the actual time for any given request could be less than or considerably more than the average.)  When a request times out, this in turn reduces the throughput in terms of requests that get completed, because the work performed on each timed out requests is (typically) wasted.

---

Unless the requests entail talking to slow external services, I'd advise you to REDUCE the number of threads to no more than 200 ... the Tomcat default<sup>2</sup>.  I expect that this will increase the system throughput.  It won't necessarily let you process all of those 1000 requests that were launched in that period, but I predict that it will increase the number of requests that are successfully processed.

<sup>1 - Indeed, increasing the number of threads to 1000 doesn't even mean that you will be able to accept 1000 requests.  If you have hundreds of threads in RUNNABLE state, it is likely that Tomcat's listener thread (the one that calls `ServerSocket.accept()`) will be CPU starved and won't be able to keep up with the request arrival rate.</sup>

<sup>2 - You will need to do some performance tuning on your system, but I wouldn't be surprised if reducing it even further improved things even more.  It will depend on your hardware, your application and (I expect) your backend database.</sup>

Comment: I concur with @StephenC, I have applications in production (with reasonnably high traffic) where we have reduced the maximum number of threads to 20, because they answer fast enough that the number of requests concurrently processed is around 1 or 2 on average (monitored through JMX), and when something bad happens (unresponsive web service, unusually long GC pause), we don't suddenly have 200 concurrent requests with their memory overhead to manage, which actual worsen the situation. The upper limit exists so the application doesn't exhaust resources, not to limit the throughput.