# connection refused , apache tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, http-post

I am tyring to access web app deployed on Apache Tomcat at local machine . Everything was working fine  till sometime ago  . and now i am getting this error continuously .

error :

```
     org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to `http://localhost refused
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:158)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:562)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:754)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:732)
    at TestHttpGet.main(TestHttpGet.java:45)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:327)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:193)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:180)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:385)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:546)
    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    ... 8 more
```

code line where error is :

```
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Comment: is your port correct?

Comment: Yes it was all fine (on browser its working) . I was also accessing the same web page from app in my phone also . But now this exception is everywhere

Comment: any limit on the number of threads that attempt to make the connection.

Comment: dont know . where can i get to see that ?

Comment: [refer this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600826/increase-number-of-concurrent-connections-in-tomcat-7)

Comment: k i solved my problem . i just had to restart tomcat . weird .